# PHP code not doing SQL function

Tags: php, sql

Good Day

I have a PHP code that should insert data into SQL database and also deduct credits from another table. It worked fine inserting the data into the SQL untill I added the deduct from credits string now it just deducts the credits but not update the database.

This is my code:

```
 function update_lbs($long, $lat, $msisdn, $distance)
 {
     global $host;
     global $username;
     global $password;
     global $db_name;
     $today = date("Y-m-d");
     $insertSuccessful = false;
     $new_msisdn = '0' . substr($msisdn, 2);
     if ($con = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)) {
         if (mysql_select_db($db_name)) {
             $sql = "insert into johan_lbs_log set lng = '".$long."', lat = '".$lat."',   distance = '".$distance."', msisdn = '".$msisdn."', date_time = '".$today."'";
        $sql = "Update johan_credits set credits=credits-1 Where account_nr=1";
        if (mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
            $insertSuccessful = true;
        } else {
            echo $sql;
            echo "\n" . mysql_error($con);
            echo "mysql err no : " . mysql_errno($con);
        }
      }
  }

    return $insertSuccessful;
 }
```

I need it to update johan_lbs_log with the info supplied and also deduct johan_credits by one

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Don't use SET keyword on INSERT query. It is not a standard way of writing.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran We can use `SET` inside INSERT`. :)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**warning**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only executing `update` query here

```
if (mysql_select_db($db_name)) {
    $sql = "insert into johan_lbs_log set lng = '".$long."', lat = '".$lat."',   distance = '".$distance."', msisdn = '".$msisdn."', date_time = '".$today."'";
    mysql_query($sql, $con); // you have to execute insert query too
    $sql = "Update johan_credits set credits=credits-1 Where account_nr=1";
    if (mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
    .....
```

**Note :** `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, start using `mysqli` OR `PDO`.

Comment: So basically in the mysql_query($sql, $con); i should add, 

mysql_query($sql, $sql1, $con);

and change the credit deduction as well?

Comment: @MaggieAckermann No, `mysql_query` doesn't take multiple query object as parameter. You have to use `mysql_query` 2 times for 2 query.

Comment: Great got it sorted thanks allot, we are bussy moving from mysql_* function to mysqli but needed this urgent

Answer (score 0):

Use the different name for the update statement like here you are using `$sql` for both insert and update but change the name of update to `$sql1` and then do the all the operation which u are doing for `$sql`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
function update_lbs($long, $lat, $msisdn, $distance)
 {
     global $host;
     global $username;
     global $password;
     global $db_name;
     $today = date("Y-m-d");
     $insertSuccessful = false;
     $new_msisdn = '0' . substr($msisdn, 2);
     if ($con = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)) {
         if (mysql_select_db($db_name)) {
             $sql = "update johan_lbs_log set lng = '".$long."', lat = '".$lat."',   distance = '".$distance."', msisdn = '".$msisdn."', date_time = '".$today."' where id=1"; //Insert is changed to update
             mysql_query($sql, $con); //To execute update query
             $sql1 = "Update johan_credits set credits=credits-1 Where account_nr=1";
        if (mysql_query($sql1, $con)) {
            $insertSuccessful = true;
        } else {
            echo $sql;
            echo "\n" . mysql_error($con);
            echo "mysql err no : " . mysql_errno($con);
        }
      }
  }

    return $insertSuccessful;
 }
```